# How to provide callback function to iTunes search API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, itunes-search-api

I am struggling to find a way to provide a callback function to correctly use the [iTunes Store search API](https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/).

I am trying to achieve this behaviour:

```
const getiTunes = fetch(`https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=${search}&media=movie&limit=200`)
  .then(results => results.json())
  .then(results => {
    if (results.errorMessage) throw Error(results.errorMessage)
    else setResults(results)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    //handle error
  })
```

and so far I have this:

```
const getiTunes = results =>  {
  if (results.errorMessage) throw Error(results.errorMessage)
  else setITunes(results)
}

const script = document.createElement("script")
script.src = `https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=${search}&media=movie&limit=200&callback=getiTunes`
script.async = true
document.body.appendChild(script)
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: getiTunes is not defined
```

I have also tried `&callback="getiTunes"` and `&callback=${getiTunes}` and they also fail.

These functions are being called in an `useEffect` hook in React. Is there a specific way I have to retrieve the function name?

---

*Aside*

And if I try to not provide a callback function, it will work only if the search is a new search (ie I haven't searched that term before). However, if I have (say on production URL or locally) then it will error with the following:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=spiderman&media=movie&limit=200' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value "--it has the last URL I used to search for this successfully--"...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by adding my script to handle the response to the document also.

```
const loadItunes = document.createElement("script")
loadItunes.src = `https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=${search}&media=movie&limit=200&callback=getiTunes`
loadItunes.async = true

const handleResults = document.createElement("script")

handleResults.type = "text/javascript"
handleResults.text = "function getiTunes(response) { //function code };"

document.body.appendChild(loadItunes)
document.body.appendChild(handleResults)
```

---

**Updated Answer**

I have found a better solution via [this code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/j3j31qvq2v). It perfectly solves this problem by creating a function which then hands off the response to a callback function.

```
export const fetchJSONP = (url, callback) => {
  var callbackName = "jsonp_callback_" + Math.round(100000 * Math.random())
  window[callbackName] = function (data) {
    delete window[callbackName]
    document.body.removeChild(script)
    callback(data)
  }

  var script = document.createElement("script")
  script.src = url + (url.indexOf("?") >= 0 ? "&" : "?") + "callback=" + callbackName
  document.body.appendChild(script)
}
```

I then use it in the following way:

```
const handleResponse = response => {
  //do stuff with response
}
fetchJSONP("https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=spiderman&media=movie&limit=200", handleResponse)
```

Answer (score 0):

The method you're trying is JSONP `(JSON with Padding)` method. We just need the external script and  the a function.
The external website provides a callback function  for your method.

So it sends all the data in function parameter.

by mistaken you have adden `}` to your script url

`` script.src = `https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=${search}&media=movie&limit=200&callback=getiTunes}` ``

Eg code:

```
const getiTunes=results=>{
if (results.errorMessage) throw new 
Error(results.errorMessage)
  else setITunes(results)
};
const script = document.createElement("script")
script.src = `https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=bat&media=movie&limit=200&callback=getiTunes`
script.async = true
document.body.appendChild(script);
// returns getiTunes(...someData)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have fixed that bug, however, there was another error that I can't seem to fix. I have updated the question with the new error.